# How do I check if a user has a certain role discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've just started creating my discord bot and I want to make a warn command, but I only want people with the moderator role to be able to use it. Is there a way of checking if a user has a certain role? Thanks. My code so far:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'warn',
    description: "The bot will warn the mentioned user",
    execute(message, args){
        var warnedone = message.mentions.first()
        if(author doesnt have a role with ID 712229762742878321) {
             return message.reply('can not use this command')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check for a role, you can do this:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('712229762742878321')) {
    return message.reply('can not use this command')
};
```

However, I would recommend you to check for permissions, as this would make the command not usable for people with the admin role for example. You can check for permissions like this:

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_ROLES')) {
    return message.reply(`you don't have manage roles permissions that are required to execute this command.`);
}
```

That way it will make all people with `Manage Roles` permission (usually mods and above) able to use the command.
Also, I would recommend you to change

```js
var warnedone = message.mentions.first()
```

to

```js
var warnedone = message.mentions.members.first()
```

and also, if you want to make it so you can warn people by their ID, you can do this:

```js
var warnedone = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

Let me know if this works :)

Comment: A better flag would be `KICK_MEMBERS`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'warn',
    description: "The bot will warn the mentioned user",
    execute(message, args){
        var warnedone = message.mentions.first()
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "712229762742878321")) {
             return message.reply('can not use this command')
        }
    }
}
```